# Revolution Slider - Only one video with multiple text slides

Tags: css, revolution-slider

I just want to ask is there a way that we can only use one video for `slider` but has multiple text `slider`, cause when you put the video on every `li` it will rewind rather than continously playing, is there a possibility to do that with `revolution`?